# Chunked virtual hard disk container for windows

Tags: windows-10, disk-image

I'm looking for the software that allows attaching virtual storage much like `diskpart attach vdisk`, but unlike the `*.vhd` format supports splitting the image file into relatively small image files of the size 10Mb and less.

This is needed so that regular users can efficiently store and sync such file sets on a cloud storage.

Performance drop is not a problem.

I tried `vmware-mount.exe` and a parent vmdk with 5x 20Mb vmdk extents. It mounts fine, but vmware sets a certain byte in the header of all extent files during mount which makes it unsuitable.

Comment: How do those users find out which chunks they need to upload to the cloud? If there are 2 GB of changes, will they upload 400 files or more?

Comment: @ThomasWeller The cloud software is supposed to check the file modification date.

Comment: Okay, that's true. I'd expect that software to work like `rsync` and does the 10 MB splitting internally while syncing. `bvckup` calls that "delta copying"

Comment: Ok, obviously [nextcloud does not support delta sync](https://github.com/nextcloud/server/issues/417)